# How do I remove pieces of my porch ceiling/soffit? (aluminum?)

Tags: ceiling, soffit, porch

I need to temporarily remove a piece of my front porch's ceiling/soffit.  How can I do this?

Each section of the ceiling seems locked to the next section and I can't seperate them.

[image: Porch roof]

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, they're nailed on hidden flanges. You'll want to disassemble one end (wherever it's easiest to remove the fascia and/or trim channel) and pull nails one at a time. Be sure to keep track of order because they may vary in length somewhat.

Attempting to remove one panel in the middle of the run is almost guaranteed to result in damage.